# Redirecting Powershell foreach loop output to txt file

Tags: powershell, loops, redirect, output

I'm currently using a simple Powershell script that takes a txt list of email addresses, and within Exchange Online, converts them to shared mailboxes, which is working correctly. I'm forcing warnings to occur by listing mailboxes that are already shared mailboxes, and forcing errors to occur by listing non-existant mailboxes. I'm trying to redirect the output to a txt file, so I can have a saved list of all the warnings and errors. My script keeps generating a blank txt file though.

```
$Mailboxes = Get-Content -Path .\Convert.txt

$logs = foreach ($Mailbox in $Mailboxes) {
    Set-Mailbox -Identity $Mailbox -Type Shared

}
$logs | Out-File -FilePath logs.txt -Append
```

Instead of Out-File, I've also tried using `$logs *>> logs.txt` and `Add-Content`.
I've also tried removing the output from the script and running `.\convert.ps1 *> logs.txt` in the console.
Lastly, I've tried changing the Foreach loop to a Foreach-Object loop as well, which also failed, but I may have not used that loop correctly.

With the help of another forum member, I'm now using

```
Get-Content -Path .\Convert.txt | & {
    process {
        Set-Mailbox -Identity $_ -Type Shared -ErrorAction Continue -WarningAction Continue
    }
} *>&1 | ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Type    = $_.GetType().Name
        Message = $_.ToString()
    }
} | Out-File -Filepath logs.txt -Append
```

With this script, I'm still seeing warnings in the console and they aren't populating my logs.txt file, but errors correctly being logged now.

Comment: Move the redirection `*>&1` to the end of the Set-Mailbox command

Answer (score 0):

It's probably best just to go with try/catch here to ensure that you catch terminating and non-terminating errors in the same way

```
$Mailboxes = Get-Content -Path .\Convert.txt
$logs = foreach ($Mailbox in $Mailboxes) {
    try {
        Set-Mailbox -Identity $Mailbox -Type Shared -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    catch {
        # Inside catch $_ will be the error record object.  Use .ToString() method to get the error message
        "ERROR: " + $_.ToString()
    }
}
# logs will contain any standard output as well as the error message strings
$logs | Out-File -FilePath logs.txt -Append
```

If you only want to capture the errors in the log or want to have a separate log for the errors you can write the messages to the log directly from the catch block

```
$Mailboxes = Get-Content -Path .\Convert.txt
$logs = foreach ($Mailbox in $Mailboxes) {
    try {
        Set-Mailbox -Identity $Mailbox -Type Shared -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    catch {
        # Inside catch $_ will be the error record object.  Use .ToString() method to get the error message
        # Send error message to log using out-file or set-content
        "ERROR: " + $_.ToString() | Out-File -FilePath errors.txt -Append
    }
}
# logs will contain only standard output 
$logs
```

See:

- [Everything you wanted to know about exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-exceptions?view=powershell-7.2)
- [about_Try_Catch_Finally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally?view=powershell-7.2)
- Another option is using [-ErrorVariable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters?view=powershell-7.2#-errorvariable) Parameter